# Given a list index, how can I find the block and block index for that element in a Rootish ArrayStack Mathematically?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, data-structures

Suppose for example I was given a large number `i` as a list index and wanted to figure out which block and block index that element in the list index corresponded to in a Rootish ArrayStack. For example:

```
List index i = 8, I know that I am in block r = 3 and within that block, I am at index 2
```

Since this list index is small, I can do the calculation with a small sketch of the Rootish ArrayStack, but for much larger list indexes this is no longer a reasonable option. Is there some sort of mathematical equation for which I can plug in my list index and solve for this?

Thanks

Comment: To solve r for a given i requires solving a specific quadratic equation which is a function of i.  Once you have r, the block is straightforward.  The quadratic will have two roots; the positive root is r.  Are you looking for a general description of the equations (and you will solve the details of the equations), or specific java code to solve r and index for a given i?

Comment: I am looking for the general mathematical equation that I can use to manually calculate r and the index in r. Would you be able to provide the quadratic equation and possibly an example using a specific list index i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminology: i represents the index (in example = 8), b represents the block (3), and j represents the index in b (2)

1. Solve for ceiling b;  (b+1)(b+2)/2 = i+1;  (only the positive root applies)
2. Solve for j;  j = i - b*(b+1)/2;

Example:  For the case you provided; i=8

1. The first quadratic has roots -6, 3 (after ceiling) => Choose 3
2. j = 8-6=2

With a fixed quadratic you can come up a formula to solve for the positive root.